# Как сделать анимацию картинки в SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, анимация, button, animate, swiftui

Всем привет, помогите разобраться, как сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку сверху вниз падала картинка, была разных размеров (например: 64х64, 128х128) и падала не только по центру, а в разных местах экрана?

Также, хотелось бы узнать, как сделать, чтоб допустим при апгрейде за 100 баллов, счетчик считал сам +1, +10, +100 и так далее каждую секунду, ну и соответственно автоанимация падающей картинки.

Хочу сделать типа Cookie Clicker для себя, но пока только учусь.

```
@State var Count: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    ZStack {

        VStack {
            Text("\(Count) Cookies")

        Button(action: {
            self.Count += 1
        }) {
            Image("cookie").renderingMode(.original)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UIView animate](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/uiview-animation-in-swift-3-2b499abb58c5)

[animate](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/11/performing-ios-animations-views-uikit-uiview/)

Посмотрите эти ссылки. Они дадут вам базу и вы сможете переделать так как вам нужно. В этом посте слишком много вопрос. Вам лучше разделить их на несколько постов.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ сделать анимацию уменьшения кнопки при нажатии, а как сделать чтоб после уменьшения она вернулась в исходное состояние?

```
VStack {
    Text("\(Count) Cookies")

    Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
            self.Count += 1
            self.buttonScale = 0.5
        }
    }) {
        Image("cookie").renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                .shadow(radius: 3)
                .scaleEffect(self.buttonScale)
    }
}
```